# Java netbeans jar file change

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have two files A.java and B.java(B is my main class) in a single project. In dist folder of project I have java executable jar file of A, but i want executable jar file for B.
I had already tried clean and build but file does not change.
Please Help

Comment: How are you building the jar? Maven? Please add more details.

Comment: In neatbeans 8.1 using Swing.

Comment: Do you have any build tool (like maven or ant) or you just use the netbeans to build your project?

Comment: Only using Netbeans , actutally i m new in Java Coding

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans : open projet properties, then select "Run" in categories and enter correct "Main class".

Comment: Already done that, my main class is B only, i need executable jar file for B.

Comment: What is the exact problem with the jar file generated with netbeans ? The result is not the expected result if you launch it ?

Comment: Netbeans is generating jar file for A but i need jar file of class B.

Comment: What do you mean by "generating jar file for A"? Is it simply the name of the jar ? Please launch java -jar yourjar.jar and check the result.

Comment: When I 'clean and build' the project, A.jar is generated in dist folder, i need B.jar , Both A.java and B. java are present in same project and B.java is my main class.

Comment: Launch : java -jar A.jar. This jar contains all classes (A and B) and there is a manifest file which specify that B is the Main Class.

Answer (score 0):

Just Right Click your Project -> Choose Properties -> Run -> Specify as " B " (class you want to run)

Comment: Project is executing perfectly inside IDE, i just need jar file of B(main class) instead of A, to execute Outside the IDE

Comment: I don't have .jar file for B , so can't run it on cmd.

Comment: Executable jar files will be created only one for a project according to your project , that jar will start run from the java code that u specify in run property. .jar will not be created seperately for A class and seperately for B class. You need to call A class from your B class,since B is your main class. If you want you can also change the name of the executable jar file being created in project properties.

Comment: ok, so what if i delete, A.jar , then any method to get B.jar?

Comment: I am unable to change name of jar file in project properties, they are pre-defined.

Comment: If you delete the jar you can rebuild it by Project -> Build option or Run option.If you want the jar file name to be created as B.jar you can specify in project properties.Check in application property, i guess.But you can change in properties window.